# YouTube API, get 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, youtube

I'm working on YouTube api which gets the current viewer count and changes the titel to the current viewer count, like Tom Scott's video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxV14h0kFs0).

The function getVideoInfo works fine. Although when I try to change the title, I get a *403 error,* saying the *YouTube video* domain is forbidden.

Terminal error:
`Something went wrong with updating...Error: Forbidden`

How can I get the information and pass the 403 forbidden error? Is it something to do with the Google Developer Console API settings or may with the code below?

```
        //getVideoInfo use videoId to get video information from YouTube api.
          function getVideoInfo(auth) {
            var youtube = google.youtube('v3');
            var videoId = 'XXXXXX';
              youtube.videos.list({
                auth: auth,
                part: 'id,snippet,statistics',
                id: videoId,
              }, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log('Something went wrong....' + err);
                  return;
                }

        //Check if it recieves data and check viewcount.
                var videos = response.data.items;
                var views = videos[0].statistics.viewCount;

                if (videos.length == 0) {
                  console.log('We found nothing');
                } else {
                  console.log('This video has %s views', views);

                  var result = response.data.items[0];
                  updateVideo(auth, result);;
              }

        //Update the title with the new title, 'View count video: {views}'
              function updateVideo(id, snippet) {
                var youtube = google.youtube('v3');
                var videoTitle = videos[0].snippet.title = 'View count video: ' + views;
                console.log('Updating video to %s', videoTitle);

                youtube.videos.update({
                  auth,
                  part: 'snippet',
                  resource: {id, snippet},
                }, function(err, response) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log('Something went wrong with updating...' + err);
                    return;
                  }
                  if (videos.length > 0) {
                    console.log('Done.')
                  }
                })

              }
              })
          }
```

Comment: Please quote error messages _verbatim_, instead of giving us a paraphrased version.

Comment: The terminal prints out `Something went wrong with updating...Error: Forbidden`

Comment: Did you check if `response` contains anything?

Comment: Yes, i get this...

 `code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      domain: 'youtube.video',
      reason: 'forbidden',
      message: 'Forbidden'
    }`